# password show/hide fontawesome icon problem and not placed into input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
<label>Password</label>
<div class="input-group" id="show_hide_password">
 <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password">
 <div class="input-group-addon">
 <a href=""><i class="fas fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

its output is like this:
[Here is my code output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3OZ9.jpg)

The problem is right side icon is:

1. fa-eye-slash not changing to fa-eye
2. right side icon is not placed inside the input field

**Update**
I forget to post my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show_hide_password a").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#show_hide_password input').attr("type") == "text"){
            $('#show_hide_password input').attr('type', 'password');
            $('#show_hide_password i').addClass( "fa-eye-slash" );
            $('#show_hide_password i').removeClass( "fa-eye" );
        }else if($('#show_hide_password input').attr("type") == "password"){
            $('#show_hide_password input').attr('type', 'text');
            $('#show_hide_password i').removeClass( "fa-eye-slash" );
            $('#show_hide_password i').addClass( "fa-eye" );
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks & Best Regards

Comment: Did you place the font awesome CDN in your head? Are you using other FA icons that are working in your project?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @dalelandry yes I added like this in my head html tag: `<script src='https://use.fontawesome.com/b9bdbd120a.js'></script>`

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for your guidance. I am studying it

Comment: you need `class="input-group-text"`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Bootstrap v4.5.2. Where I need this `class="input-group-text" `

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/input-group/#basic-example

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you are right one problem fixed i.e. eye icon but now show/hide not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you need `class="input-group-text"`, also in 5.6 its `input-group-append` not `input-group-addon`.

Then to toggle the show/hide, put a class on the link, then on click, find the outer `.input-group` cache it into a var so can reuse it to [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector) the other elements, then toggle them, can use a ternary for input type and [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) for the icon.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // target the link
  $(".toggle_hide_password").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    // get input group of clicked link
    var input_group = $(this).closest('.input-group')

    // find the input, within the input group
    var input = input_group.find('input.form-control')

    // find the icon, within the input group
    var icon = input_group.find('i')

    // toggle field type
    input.attr('type', input.attr("type") === "text" ? 'password' : 'text')

    // toggle icon class
    icon.toggleClass('fa-eye-slash fa-eye')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Password</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text">
        <a href="#" class="toggle_hide_password">
          <i class="fas fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart. Appreciated!!